# How to use authinfo credentials with Magit to push/pull to Overleaf

Tags: magit, authinfo

[Overleaf allows git](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub#The_Overleaf_Git-Bridge) for some users. I have been using emacs and magit with overleaf since some time by providing username-password at each git push or git pull.

#### What I want

Now I want to configure magit to use username and password from my `.authinfo` file so that it does not ask me credentials at each push or pull.

#### What I have

- Overleaf does not allow ssh public key based authentication right now.
- Using GNU Emacs 27.1 with Magit 20201218.1819.
- authinfo entry

`machine git.overleaf.com port 443 login email@example.com password eX@mp1e`

I have also tried `machine https://git.overleaf.com login email@example.com password eX@mp1e`

- magit config

```lisp
(use-package magit
  :init     
    (setq auth-source-debug 'trivia)
  :config
    (add-hook 'magit-process-find-password-functions 'magit-process-password-auth-source))
```

#### What I get

When I try to do a git push, it asks for my username. After I type in my email address (which is my username), it returns this message:

```lisp
auth-source-search: found 1 results (max 1) matching (:max 1 :host "git.overleaf.com" :user "email@example.com")
```

And the committed changes get pushed successfully. So I guess this is a minor success since magit is able to lookup the password from the authinfo file when I provide the username.

Comment: I guess that clarifying if you're able to push and telling how your remotes looks like will help.

Comment: I'm able to push after I type the username (which is my email). 
I'm not sure what you mean by 'how your remote looks like'.
I want to push without typing the username.

Comment: please add all the info to the question, comments may not be read, or deleted.

Comment: About the remotes, I mean the url your remote is using. I guess this probably will work: `https://username@git.overleaf.com/` if your username contains a `@` usually replacing it with `%40` does the trick from the command line, I never tried with authinfo file. Also there is the git credential system as last resort.

Comment: There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3806) that references the `@` related to overleaf. I hope to try your suggestion tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but since I solved the username lookup part I want to share in the hopes that someone finds it useful.

I was able to use this question to get the password lookup working using the info from OP. Similarly, I was prompted to enter my username.

I solved the username lookup by adding the following line to ~/.gitconfig:

```
[url "https://USERNAME@gitlab.company.example"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.company.example
```